# How to convert the array to string in single array

Tags: php, arrays, string

Below are the result of array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => cate
            [2] => category
        )

)
```

I want the result to be

```
 $availableTags = ["test","cate","category"];
```

How to do this in codeigniter php

Comment: try using json_encode() and json_decode() functions

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing code-igniter specific. The array currently looks like this: `[["test","cate","category"]]`, so just do `$availableTags = $originalArray[0];`

To copy:

```
$availableTags = array_slice($originalArray[0],0);
```

And to stringify:

```
echo json_encode($availableTags);
```

Comment: @user2484538: After a quick look at your profile, I've noticed you've yet to accept your first answer. On this site, the way to say thanks it [by accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), not by commenting. Please consider accepting... there's a +2 reputation bonus in it for you...

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = $array[0];
```

Should be enough

```
$array = [["test","cate","category"]];
var_dump ($array);

$array = $array[0];
var_dump ($array);
```

Output :

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(4) "cate" [2]=> string(8) "category" } } 
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(4) "cate" [2]=> string(8) "category" }
```

Comment: Do you really get this format `["test","cate","category"]`? `var_dump($array);`

Comment: @Bora: The way the OP's snippet looks, it could be that all he wants is an array, since the later versions of PHP treat `[]` as valid syntax for an array...

Comment: @Bora Edited my answer with an output, it gives the correct format.

Comment: I think, he doesnt want this format. He already has array. You just extract the array.

Comment: @Bora He clearly wants an array, look at the wanted result he gave and  what Elias Von Ootegem said.

Comment: @C.Malet: I'm not too sure he wants an array, though. I also included `json_encode` in my answer, in case OP wants a string...

Answer (score 0):

**Short and simpler way** [A Mix of json_encode and str_replace and explode]

```
<?php
$data = array('foo',
    'baz',
    'cow',
    'php',
     array('bar','dog','xml'));

//Results as string
$stringRes = str_replace(array('[', '"',']'), '' , json_encode($data));

//Results as array
$arrayRes  = explode(',', str_replace(array('[', '"',']'), '' , json_encode($data)));

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> foo,baz,cow,php,bar,dog,xml
>   
> Array ( [0] => foo [1] => baz [2] => cow [3] => php [4] => bar [5] => dog [6] => xml )